# What type of ladybug is this?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification

I found this insect, whatever it is, at first I thought it was a ladybug. But I think it's a carpet beetle. What does it eat? It doesn't eat raisins. And it's trying to escape.
How can I make a habitat for it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhhkD.jpg]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please visit the [help] and take a [tour]. For ID we would need a location in the world, where you found the insect (inside, outside, on what surface) and preferably close-up photos from multiple angles.

Comment: Crosspost of https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/61200/20139

Comment: Without more details, I can confirm it looks like a black one with yellow dots. Where did you see it?  What time of day?  What was the weather?

Comment: I saw it on my armchair at the evening.

Comment: The weather was moderate. And by the way, the armchair had lots of clothes on it. It can fly for short distances.

Answer (score 2):

That does indeed look rather like a Carpet Beetle, although I am not a particular expert on beetles.  The size, antenna shape and color/pattern are consistent with Carpet Beetle, but would be a little off for the Ladybirds that I am familiar with.

As for diet, here's a link [ https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef601 ] that might potentially be helpful, but I'm not sure how much longer the adults will be eating - I don't know if they overwinter in a sort of dormant state, the way some other beetles do, but I'm also not sure I'd recommend trying to keep it.  Still, don't let me discourage you - some of the greatest naturalists kept all sorts of things simply to find out what they were like and how they lived.  That's something we really need more of.